# what's a small, medium, and large Scope in penetration testing?

Tags: penetration-test

I've been diving into the world of penetration testing regarding PM, and I'm curious about how you all define the scope of such tests. I often hear terms like "small scope," "medium scope," and "large-scope" thrown around, but it seems somewhat subjective.

So, I'd like to hear your thoughts! When it comes to penetration testing, what do you consider small, medium, and large scopes? How would you categorize the testing of various assets such as firewalls, cameras, voice IP phones, workstations, video devices, servers, databases, and internal web apps? how many hosts in a node need to have to be considered small to large?

Comment: The reason they sound subjective is because they are.

Comment: There is no definition.

Answer (score 0):

This is far too subjective for you to get a much of an answer. For some teams a "small" scope might be a simple webapp with two pages; for others it might be a network with a hundred devices on it.

Terms like "small" and "large" are relative - so if you're going to use them then you need to decide what they mean in the context of your team, rather than trying to generalise them.